# jQuery .tagcloud() и .button() как написать?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="tagwidget">
    <h4>Tags Widget</h4>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Kitesurf</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Super</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Duper</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Theme</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Men</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Women</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Equipment</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Best</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Accessories</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Men</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Apparel</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Super</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Duber</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Theme</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Responsiv</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Men</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Women</span>
    <span class="tag-cloud">Equipment</span>
</div>

 jQuery ---> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tagwidget').tagcloud(
        max: 1;-------?????
    );

    });

    или button хотя следующее:  
               $(function() {
$( "span" ).button();
     });
```

Правильно ли написаны коды?

Эта картинка должна быть соответствовать кодам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оба кода у меня не сработали((